# collective form convert html form

Tags: html, laravel, laravelcollective

This is laravel **collective form**, This is a dropdown field, its connect with **database**. How can i convert normal html form???

```
 {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> xyz\AddController@store', 'id'=> 'form']) !!}

    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        {!! Form::label('student_id', 'Students:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('student_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] + $students , null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'student', 'name'=>'student_id'])!!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**I want to convert format like this**

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-5">
        <label for="qty">Traded Quantity</label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="form-control" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If students list is coming through database then select tag can be like this,

```
<select id="student" class="form_control" name="student_id">
 <option>Choose Options</option>
  @foreach($students as $student)
   <option value="{{$student->id}}">{{$student->id}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```